# I am having trouble in my JavaScript code trying to change a variable in a class with a keydown event hander

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In my update, the posX is supposed to be changed when the <kbd>w</kbd> key is pressed but nothing happens. If I get rid of the if statement and just have it change whenever the update function is called it works.

```
class FPlayer {

    constructor(windowWidth, windowHeight, width, height, posX, posY) {

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.posX = posX;
        this.posY = posY;
        this.windowWidth = windowWidth;
        this.windowHeight = windowHeight;
        this.x = 0;

        addEventListener("keydown", this.handler);
    }

    update() {

        if(this.x == 87) {

            this.posX += 2;
        }
    }
    draw() {

        c.beginPath();
        c.fillStyle = "blue";
        c.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);
        c.closePath();
    }

    handler(event) {

        this.x = event.keyCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `w` you're referring to? I don't see it anywhere. edit: oh, you're referring to a key, not a click

Comment: if(this.x == 87). the 87 is keyCode for w

Comment: Can you show where you attach the handler?

Comment: at the end of the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work:

```
addEventListener("keydown", this.handler);
```

This just adds the function as the handler, it doesn't bind it to the correct object. Use:

```
addEventListener("keydown", this.handler.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks for the info about binding it. (: